# Retrive list item meta data into access table?

Tags: office-integration

I'm creating a report in Access based on a SharePoint list, but  I'd like to make use of the fields `Last Modified` and `Modified By`.  I imported the table into Access as a linked table, but I don't see those fields.  How can I access (read) those fields in Access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the answer.  Those fields are linked, but are hidden on the table by default.

You must right click the table headers and click `Unhide Columns...` then select the hidden columns you desire to work with.